# Save Django Model when list_editable fields are changed in Django Admin change_list view

Tags: django

I have a Django Model which I'm trying to update from the Admin change_list view when a field that is listed in list_editable has a change event fired. Right now the only way to save the updates is by clicking a "Save" button and then the page reloads. I don't want the page to reload at all. I just want it to update the model asynchronously.

For example I have the following model.

```
class Example(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In the Admin Form I have

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "name",
        "hide"
    ]

    list_editable = [
        "name",
        "hide"
    ]
```

When viewing the change list for Examples now I will see the values listed out with an editable text input for name and a checkbox for hide.

I would like to listen for events on those inputs and when they are fired send an async request to update the specific model.

**UPDATE**

This is what I have right now.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    (function($) {
        $(".field-name .vTextField").on("change",function (event) {
            $('#changelist-form').submit()
        })
        $('#changelist-form').submit(function(event) { // On form submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: "POST", // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function(e, x, r) { // on error..
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault()
            return false;
        });
    })(django.jQuery);
})
```

I can see this firing in the network requests and can verify that the serialized data being sent is updated. The response is a 200, but when I refresh the page the data has not been updated.

**UPDATE**
At this point I'm giving up on sending this data to Django and will be sending the serialized data to a custom endpoint and parse through and save the data in a custom save function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your Admin Model add the following

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
       js = ("js/admin/example.js")

    list_display = [
        "name",
        "hide"
    ]

    list_editable = [
        "name",
        "hide"
    ]
```

**example.js**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    (function($) {
        $(".field-name .vTextField").on("change",function (event) {
            submit()
        })
        
        function getFormData($form){
            var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
            var indexed_array = {};
            $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
                indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
            });
            return indexed_array;
        }

        function submit(){
            $.ajax({ 
                data: getFormData($('#changelist-form')),
                type: "POST",
                url: '/api/save-example',
                success: function(response) { 
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function(e, x, r) { 
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
        }

    })(django.jQuery);
})
```

I'm using Django Rest Framework so I created a POST endpoint, but you could also do this in a Django View that is listening for a POST.

When you execute the post Django will send the data categorized by the row number and field name, like so.

```
form-0-id : 1
form-0-name: example-name
form-0-hide: false
form-0-example_parent: 100

form-1-id : 2
form-1-name: example-name-two
form-1-hide: true
form-1-example_parent: 200
```

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def save_example(request):

    try:
        total_rows = int(request.POST.get("form-TOTAL_FORMS"))
        prefix = "form-"
        form_fields = {
            "id": "id",
            "name": "name",
            "hide": "hide",
            "example_parent": "example_parent_id",
        }

        for x in range(total_rows):
            item = {}
            for key, val in form_fields.items():
                post_field = prefix + str(x) + "-" + key
                field = val
                if key == "id":
                    id = request.POST.get(post_field)
                else:
                    item[field] = request.POST.get(post_field)

            Example.objects.filter(id=id).update(**item)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    except Exception as e:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

***Note***

`total_rows = int(request.POST.get("form-TOTAL_FORMS"))` which lets you know how to loop through all the form data that is passed back.

This doesn't take different values into consideration. (i.e. Checkboxes will return an `on` value but no value if not checked.

You will need to update your save_example function accordingly.